# What is -z in if [ -z "${FILE_LIST}" ]

Tags: shell

Came across this, what is `-z` in the shell script `if [ -z "${FILE_LIST}" ]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[` is the same as `test`. And `man test` gives:

```
   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
```

Note: On some platforms, `[` is a symlink or hardlink to `test`

Comment: can you identify a platform where `man [` is unavailable yet `man test` is available?

Comment: what OS are you running?  Plus, when you write `man test` its assumed you were talking about man test on your computer, not google :)

Comment: A gentoo. But, yeah, I also checked on a debian and `man [` is ok there.

Answer (score 3):

From `help test`:

```
  -z STRING      True if string is empty.
```

Answer (score 2):

-z tests for a zero-length string.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you're using bash, then it would return true if the length of the string is zero (so in your case, there are no files in the list).