# What does -n in if [ -n "${TEMP_FILE_LIST}" ] do?

Tags: shell, unix

What does `-n` in `if [ -n "${TEMP_FILE_LIST}" ]` do for this shell script?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From `help test`:

```
  -n STRING
     STRING      True if string is not empty.
```

Answer (score 6):

-n tests for a non-zero-length string

Comment: @ChinBoon, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629201/what-is-z-in-if-z-file-list

Answer (score 5):

```
if [ -n "${TEMP_FILE_LIST}" ]
```

tests if the argument `"${TEMP_FILE_LIST}"` does not have zero length.

You can also check

```
if [ ! -z "${TEMP_FILE_LIST}" ]
```